# Javascript error only on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I've a javascript that works well in all browser but Safari.

The code is pretty easy and basically when I change the value of a text field (numeric value) the content of a `<b>` is changed

Here the code

```
$(document).on('change', '.priceAmount', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $((e.target).closest('div.price_info')).find('> .supplierPrice').html(
 ($(this).val() + 10);
});
```

the corrisponding HTML is

```
<div class="price_info">        
   <input type="number" class="priceAmount">    
   <b class="supplierPrice">20</b>
</div>
```

The `20` inside the `<b>` is inserted by the js when I enter `10` in the input box.

Safari gives me this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(e.target).closest('div.price_info')')
```

It seems like Safari doesn't receive the element when the event is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **$(this)** instead of e.target. Suggested to use **parseInt**

```
$(document).on('change', '.priceAmount', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).closest('div.price_info').find('.supplierPrice').html(parseInt($(this).val()) + 10);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5twnrwd/)

Comment: Extra `)` after `closest`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `$` of the `e.target`:

```
$($(e.target).closest('div.price_info'))
//^
    .find('> .supplierPrice').html(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + 10);
```

Alternatively, you can also use `$(this)`:

```
$(this).closest('div.price_info')
    .children('.supplierPrice')
    .html(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + 10);
```

**Syntax Error** in your code:

Extra `(` after `html` method:

```
$((e.target).closest('div.price_info')).find('> .supplierPrice').html(
 ($(this).val() + 10);
//^
```